# JavaScript MouseOver Image

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover

I am trying to change the picture by using mouseover however it doesn't seem to be working? can anyone help? here is my code

```
<img id="myImg" src="Nov1.jpg" alt="November" style="width:452px;height:127px">

  <script>
  $('#myImg').hover(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', '/folder/nov2014.jpg');
   }, function() {
   $(this).attr('src', '/folder/Nov1.jpg');
  });


  </script>
```

Comment: '/' in the first position means the root of the system. Use relative ways. Also, try to use not `hover`, but `mouseover` and `mouseout`

Comment: Also, when you handle `mouseout` you change `src` of image not back to "Nov1.jpg", but to '/folder/Nov1.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

There might be two reasons that can create such problem.

1. See if you've included the *jQuery* library before using it.
2. You have to put your *code* inside **$(document).ready(function(){** //here your code goes **});**

Try this way,

**HTML :**

```
<img id="myImg" src="http://www.allgraphics123.com/ag/01/14142/14142.gif" />
```

**jQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myImg').hover(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', 'http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/265489/120305665/stock-vector-cartoon-parrot-vector-clip-art-illustration-with-simple-gradients-all-in-a-single-layer-120305665.jpg');
        }, function() {
        $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.allgraphics123.com/ag/01/14142/14142.gif');
    });
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/f6kcmL9e/)

**Why your code didn't work?????**

Before manipulating any DOM element, the page must be loaded first. So one question arises that,

*How would I know if the page has already been loaded!!!*

Here comes *$(document).ready();* as a helping hand from *jQuery*. It let javaScript execute the code that it contains when the DOM elements are ready for use. So as a developer you don't need to worry if DOM has been loaded or not.

And that's the reason that you were going to manipulate the DOM element #myImg before it has been availabe for use. And your javaScript/jQuery code couldn't find that you are asking for.

[***I just rephrased this documentation*** **:** **Here**](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
  <img id="myImg" src="Nov1.jpg" alt="November" style="width:452px;height:127px">

  <script>

    $("#myImg")
            .mouseover(function() {
                $(this).attr("src", "/folder/nov2014.jpg");
            })
            .mouseout(function() {
                $(this).attr("src", "/folder/Nov1.jpg");
            });   
  </script>
```